# Querying multiple database in a microservice architecture

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, microservices

I am currently working on a project where we use microservice architecture. I am also somewhat new to this architecture and have had a few concerns. I understand the concept of microservices in general and also how we can have one database per service. This brings me to a point where I get confused on how to pull data from different databases for a particular user.

**Scenario**
Assuming I have a `Users` and a `Posts` service with their schema like this

*User*

```
const schema = {
  name: String
  id: String
  ...
}
```

**Post**

```
const schema = {
  text: String
  user: Id // reference of the user who made this post.
}
```

Now on the UI, I want to load a set of posts and the associated users who made the post, how do I get a `Post` alongside the `User` who made the respective Post. I am using MongoDB, how do I populate data that are stored in other databases? I am also using Kafka handle async operations, how do I leverage Kafka for this usecase? Or is there a much better way of doing this? The final response of a Post could be something like this.

```
{
 text: 'Some random message',
 user: {
  name: 'John Doe',
  id: 1234
 }
}
```

Also, I know I could make a call to the `User` service to get the User, then make a call to the Post service to get the Post and merge both objects together, but is there a much better option than this basically? I am thinking in cases where I want to do multiple lookups for a user, e.g to get a User and their associated Posts, Messages, etc, how can I handle scenarios like this, are their any techniques I could leverage for situations like this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: According to my experience, It is not compulsory to use two different databases for different services every time. You can have services that are using the same database but yes working on the different collections.

You should split your service in such a way that both services can work independently or have the least dependency. In your both services are highly dependent on each other

Comment: @HandsomeCoder I am quite aware of that, but I am just being curious about how this works basically. I have been doing a bit of research since yesterday and came across API Composition and CQRS as patterns to Query databases, but if you have more leads on this, I'd be very glad to hear your opinion. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is service boundaries are too granular.  I would recommend aligning your services to bounded contexts (https://martinfowler.com/bliki/BoundedContext.html).  For example if you have a "blog" service with posts and users, its quite alright for the blog service to contain both a mongo and relational database  for the different models.

Then you ask the service "give me posts for a user" and it is responsible for combining that data as part of its logic.

If you MUST keep them separate (which i would not recommend for the exact problem you are having) then I would keep a lightweight cache of usernames inside the posts service.

Use that to populate the usernames into the post when you return one.  You can either update the cache on a regular basis using events, polling, batches.  Or just query the user service on a cache-miss.

When dealing with distributed systems you cannot rely on consistency and synchronous, stable communication like you can in a monolith.